# boost circular_buffer push_back compilation error

Tags: c++, boost, circular-buffer

I am implementing `boost::circular_buffer` in `boost::managed_shared_memory`. I used the sample code demonstrating vector in shared memory [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/interprocess/quick_guide.html#interprocess.quick_guide.qg_interprocess_container). I made the following changes :

`1) typedef boost::circular_buffer<int, ShmemAllocatorCB> MyCircularBuffer;`

`2) MyCircularBuffer *circbuff = segment.construct<MyCircularBuffer>("MyCB")(alloc_inst);`

`3) circbuff->push_back(1);`

The code is giving a compile error on line #3. The error is

`error C2665: 'operator new' : none of the 5 overloads could convert all the argument types c:\boost2005\boost\circular_buffer\base.hpp 1470`

From the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost/circular_buffer.html), I understand the push_back function is expecting one of these 3 forms :

`void push_back(param_value_type);
  void push_back(rvalue_type);
  void push_back();`

I tried the empty parameter call, tried casting the 1 into param_value_type, rvalue_type but none of them seem to work. This might be a simple mistake but I have not been able to figure this out for quite some time now. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

**Edit:**

`typedef allocator<int, managed_shared_memory::segment_manager>  ShmemAllocatorCB;`

`managed_shared_memory segment(create_only, "MySharedMemory", 65536);`

`const ShmemAllocatorCB alloc_inst (segment.get_segment_manager());`

Comment: Well, the problem seems to be to construct the object rather than pushing it. I suspect the error will persist if you comment in the push_back call. I think you need to elaborate more. In particular: how is the `ShmemAllocatorCB` defined and what is `alloc_inst`?

Comment: @hfhc2 : Please check the edit. The error is introduced exactly at the push_back() call. If I comment it out the program compiles just fine.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like Boost's circular buffer uses raw pointers at some point in time for debugging. This, unfortunately, is prohibitive:

- [Container requirements for Boost.Interprocess allocators](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/interprocess/allocators_containers.html#interprocess.allocators_containers.containers_explained.stl_container_requirements)

Boost provides some reference on the subject:

- [Compatibility with Interprocess library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/circular_buffer/implementation.html#circular_buffer.implementation.compatibility_with_interprocess_)

In summary, compile your code without circular_buffer debugging support by defining either `BOOST_CB_DISABLE_DEBUG` or `NDEBUG` preprocessor defines.

## EDIT: Here is a working example:

(tested with `BOOST_LIB_VERSION` = `1_49`)

```
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/allocators/allocator.hpp>
#include <boost/circular_buffer.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib> //std::system

using namespace boost::interprocess;

//Define an STL compatible allocator of ints that allocates from the managed_shared_memory.
//This allocator will allow placing containers in the segment
typedef allocator<int, managed_shared_memory::segment_manager>  ShmemAllocatorCB;

//Alias a vector that uses the previous STL-like allocator so that allocates
//its values from the segment
typedef boost::circular_buffer<int, ShmemAllocatorCB> MyCircularBuffer;

//Main function. For parent process argc == 1, for child process argc == 2
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   if(argc == 1){ //Parent process
      //Remove shared memory on construction and destruction
      struct shm_remove
      {
         shm_remove() { shared_memory_object::remove("MySharedMemory"); }
         ~shm_remove(){ shared_memory_object::remove("MySharedMemory"); }
      } remover;

      //Create a new segment with given name and size
      managed_shared_memory segment(create_only, "MySharedMemory", 65536);

      //Initialize shared memory STL-compatible allocator
      const ShmemAllocatorCB alloc_inst (segment.get_segment_manager());

      //Construct a buffer named "MyCB" in shared memory with argument 10 (for size) and alloc_inst
      MyCircularBuffer *circbuff = segment.construct<MyCircularBuffer>("MyCB")(10, alloc_inst);

      for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)  //Insert data in the buffer, with overflows
         circbuff->push_back(i);

      //Launch child process
      std::string s(argv[0]); s += " child ";
      if(0 != std::system(s.c_str()))
         return 1;

      //Check child has destroyed the buffer
      if(segment.find<MyCircularBuffer>("MyCB").first)
         return 1;
   }
   else{ //Child process
      //Open the managed segment
      managed_shared_memory segment(open_only, "MySharedMemory");

      //Find the buffer using the c-string name
      MyCircularBuffer *circbuff = segment.find<MyCircularBuffer>("MyCB").first;

      //Use buffer in reverse order
      std::cout << "Child got: " << (*circbuff)[3] << "\n"; // 93

      //When done, destroy the buffer from the segment
      segment.destroy<MyCircularBuffer>("MyCB");
   }

   return 0;
};
```

To complie it:

```
g++ -DBOOST_CB_DISABLE_DEBUG -DNDEBUG cb_ipc.cpp -o cb_ipc -lboost_system -lrt
```

To run it:

```
./cb_ipc
Child got: 93
```

Comment: Beat me to it. There's also spsc_queue in Boost Lockfree that fits the purpose if there's only a single consumer/producer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22207546/shared-memory-ipc-synchronization-lock-free/22209595#22209595

Comment: All these crazy ways of doing IPC! Absolutely mad!

Comment: @ftwl : Thanks for the suggestion but I already tried that and it doesn't work. Although it is weird that if I change my build settings to Release instead of Debug, the error changes to `none of the 4 overloads could convert all the argument types` .

Comment: @sehe: Thanks for the spsc queue suggestion, I will try that out. Although,could you please comment what is wrong with respect to the orignal question. I tried using the preprocessors but that didn't work.

Comment: @Maverick the answer already gave the explanation, otherwise I would have posted the exact same answer. And yes, that made the code compile.

Comment: @ftwl:I am sorry I didnt mention before, I am using MSVC 2010 and boost 1_55. to compile this. I tried the code you posted but the error still persists. I have added the preprocessors in the project settings. Is there something else that I need to take care of in Visual Studio?

Comment: @Maverick: I'm not sure... Maybe try adding the defines to the very top of the file:
`#define BOOST_CB_DISABLE_DEBUG`
`#define NDEBUG`

Comment: @ftwl: That isn't working either. This thing is driving me crazy! Anyways, do let me know in case you figure it out at any point. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you are not setting the capacity of the circular_buffer correctly. I would imagine the capacity is zero and hence you cannot push.

After constructing the circular_buffer set the capacity to the required size.

```
#define BOOST_CB_DISABLE_DEBUG

#include <boost/circular_buffer.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/shared_memory_object.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/allocators/allocator.hpp>

using namespace boost;
using namespace boost::interprocess;

typedef allocator<T, managed_shared_memory::segment_manager> cb_alloc;
typedef circular_buffer<T, cb_alloc> cb;

managed_shared_memory* m_mem_segment;                                               
cb* m_buffer;

//  Create shared memory segment of a size able to hold the max updates.
m_mem_segment = new managed_shared_memory(open_or_create, NAMED_MEMORY, MEMORY_SIZE);       

if (m_mem_segment == nullptr) {
    return false;
}
//  Get the segement manager for allocating a circular buffer.
const cb_alloc alloc_inst(m_mem_segment->get_segment_manager());                            

//  Create a circular buffer in the shared memory segment.
m_buffer = m_mem_segment->find_or_construct<cb>(NAMED_BUFFER)(alloc_inst);                  

if (m_mem_segment == nullptr) {
    return false;
}

//  Set the capacity if not set (zero) (this must be set!)
if (m_buffer->capacity() <= 0) {                                                    
    m_buffer->set_capacity(50);
}
```

You can push to this fine, I tested with multiple processes exchanging data fine.
This is a simple example you obviously must implement your own synchronism between processes using named_mutex or semaphores etc.