# Best way to dump data from boost shared memory

Tags: c++, boost, shared-memory

I have 2 application. One writes high frequency data to boost managed shared memory, data struct being boost deque.

```
typedef boost::interprocess::allocator<REALTIME_INFO, boost::interprocess::managed_shared_memory::segment_manager> ShmemAllocator;
typedef boost::interprocess::deque<REALTIME_INFO, ShmemAllocator> MyDeque;

boost::interprocess::managed_shared_memory segment(boost::interprocess::open_or_create, "MySharedMemory",50000000); 
const ShmemAllocator alloc_inst (segment.get_segment_manager());
MyDeque *Mydeque;
Mydeque = segment.find_or_construct<MyDeque>("myd")(alloc_inst);//first ctor parameter

if(Mydeque->size() < 150000){   
    Mydeque->push_back(rtinfo);
}
else{
    Mydeque->pop_front();
    Mydeque->push_back(rtinfo);
}
```

My second application is a Qt application when pressed button reads from the shared memory and writes to a csv file. Since the data is huge I cannot write the data directly from shared memory so I tried memcpy. I could only get the first value and remaining were garbage.

```
managed_shared_memory segment (open_only, "MySharedMemory");
MyDeque *Mydeque = segment.find<MyDeque>("myd").first;
```

After getting the first pointer I tried to copy it to another `MyDeque` but I can only access the first pointer and cannot iterate remaining data.

```
memcpy(Mydeque_new, &Mydeque, Mydeque->size()*sizeof(REALTIME_INFO));
```

Can anyone suggest a better way to copy data from shared memory to a local memory.

Comment: What strategy are you using to avoid data races? From the look of yout enqueuing code, it seems you need to have concurrent access from both applications, so I imagine restricting access to the entire memory block is not going to work for you. How you handle this is going to inform which startegy is appropriate.

Comment: Can we suspect `REALTIME_INFO` is a POD? Also what @Frank said: Protect against race conditions.

Comment: @Frank Actually you are right. I tried using named_mutex but this started crashing the second application. Since the managed_shared _memory is sync automatically i thought of not using any mutex. this is still in initial phase. Can you point me to right direction in using mutex?

Comment: @user0042 REALTIME_INFO  is user defined data struct. i agree with Frank. I have also tried scoped_lock.

Comment: @brownKnight I'm afraid that depends too much on the nature of the interaction between the two executables for us to answer.

Comment: Ya thats true. The writing frequency is very high and memory takes upto 40Mb. But thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
memcpy(Mydeque_new, &Mydeque, Mydeque->size()*sizeof(REALTIME_INFO));
```

This is big fat [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) because `deque<>` is not a POD type. In fact, even the elements data is not contiguous in memory, so you can't even memcpy *that*.

- Consider using a [Boost Interprocess Message Queue](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_0/doc/html/interprocess/synchronization_mechanisms.html#interprocess.synchronization_mechanisms.message_queue)
- If there's a single consumer and a single producer, consider using `spsc_queue`: [Shared-memory IPC synchronization (lock-free)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22207546/shared-memory-ipc-synchronization-lock-free/22209595#22209595). This is a potentially lock-less solution and it has a bulk-dequeue/enqueue interface as well.